# Application published on IIS (Ip) doesn't know about my node_modules

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, npm, deployment, module

I have an asp.net core 2.2 application that I published on my IIS and can access it with http://10.23.44.105:891/"some path"(I modified the ip). In this app I instaled what I needed with npm and I use a bunch of stuff like requirejs, multiselect,bootstrap, etc. The problem is that  apparently, the app doesn't know about my node_modules.

I assume that is something related to the webconfig or I need to tell the app that the node_modules needs to be published too.

This is my webconfig file after publishing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProductManagement_WebApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 1bbb425b-0e64-410d-86e5-142483a5f132-->
```

and this is the console with all the errors

```
GET http://10.23.44.105:891/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
BaseProducts:8 

GET http://10.23.44.105:891/node_modules/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
BaseProducts:13 

GET http://10.23.44.105:891/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
BaseProducts:14

 GET http://10.23.44.105:891/node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
BaseProducts:16 

GET http://10.23.44.105:891/node_modules/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
BaseProducts:34

 GET http://10.23.44.105:891/node_modules/requirejs/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
init.js:2 

Uncaught ReferenceError: requirejs is not defined
    at init.js:2

 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at BaseProducts:245

 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

EDIT: Something besides npm install would be helpful. Sadly I had to modify some of the js files in the node_modules because of requirejs so npm install wouldn't be the best solution. I need something to force the node_modules to be on the published app as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution**. In the csproj of the project that you want to publish you need to tell that you want the node_modules includes. By default (I think) those are not included. So to include them you need to put this in there

```
`<ItemGroup>
         <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\**"   
             CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Note**: Replace the path with your path to node_modules

**ATTENTION**. You may need to delete the other references to node_modules from there. Example:

```
    <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\dialog\dialog.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\display\fullscreen.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\fold\foldgutter.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\hint\show-hint.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\lint\lint.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\merge\merge.css" />
```

or instead of "Content"is"None"

```
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\lint\json-lint.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\lint\lint.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\lint\yaml-lint.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\merge\merge.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\mode\loadmode.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\mode\multiplex.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\node_modules\codemirror\addon\mode\multiplex_test.js" />
```

I deleted those and put the first thing and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may copy required node_modules to wwwroot folder of the app (e.g. with gulp script binded as "after build" action.

Contents of the wwwroot are included in publish output and accessible later on as static files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed it just by telling .csproj to include those as well. Didn't try your solution yet.